# Trying to simulate a linux shell.Problems with simulating mkdir

Tags: c++, linux, shell, pointers

I am trying to make a c++ program to simulate a Linux shell. Nothing to fancy, just a few commands.

I am trying to do it like this:

I made a Class that tries to simulate a file system with Nodes and children.
Every node can have n children and every child has a pointer pointing to its parent.

The Node class looks like this:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node();
    Node(bool isFile);
    Node(string name);
    friend class Tree;
    bool isFile;
    vector<Node*> childs;
    string name;
    string text;
    Node *parrent;
    string names = "-";

protected:

private:



};
```

I made an addNode method that I want to use to add Nodes to my "Tree". And what I tried to do is have it like this:

```
void Tree::addNode(string name,bool isFile,string pwd)
{
size_t pos=0;
string delimiter = "\\";
string token;
Node *inserter = new Node();
Node *aux;
inserter->name=name;
inserter->isFile=isFile;
aux=&this->root;
pos = pwd.find(delimiter);
token = pwd.substr(0,pos);
pwd.erase(0,pos + delimiter.length());
if((pos = pwd.find(delimiter)) == string::npos)
{
    inserter->parrent=aux;
    if(aux->names.find(name) == string::npos)
    {
        aux->childs.push_back(inserter);
        aux->names.append(name);
        aux->names.append(" ");
    }
    else
    {

        cout << "The directory already exists" << endl;
    }
}
else
{
    while((pos = pwd.find(delimiter)) != string::npos)
    {
        token = pwd.substr(0,pos);
        pwd.erase(0,pos + delimiter.length());
        for(int i = 0; i<aux->childs.size(); i++)
        {
            if(aux->childs[i]->name.compare(token))
            {
                aux=aux->childs[i];
                cout << token << endl;
            }
        }

    }
    inserter->parrent=aux;
    if(aux->names.find(name) == string::npos)
    {
        aux->childs.push_back(inserter);
        aux->names.append(name);
        aux->names.append(" ");
    }
    else
    {

        cout << "The directory already exists" << endl;
    }
}

 }
```

So, basically, every time I call this method, I want to make sure that every directory exists, and I change the pointer aux to point at the child address, and so on.

The first if is for making directories in the root, and what's in the while for every other directory.

But, due to my bad understanding of pointers, I can't see where I go wrong.
When I add nodes in the "root" node everything works fine , but when I add nodes in any children things go bad, and I can't quite put my finger on it.

I also have a ls and cd implemented
The ls works fine, but the cd doesn't.I try to do the same thing when checking for the existance of directories, but sometmes, even if a directory doesn't exist, if you type cd "name of directroy that you are in" it just adds to pdw even if that directory doesn't exist.

Here is the cd method

```
bool Tree::exitsChild(string name,string pwd)
{
size_t pos=0;
string delimiter = "\\";
string token;
Node *aux;
aux=&root;
pos = pwd.find(delimiter);
token = pwd.substr(0,pos);
pwd.erase(0,pos + delimiter.length());
if((pos = pwd.find(delimiter)) == string::npos)
{
    if(aux->names.find(name)!= string::npos)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
else
{
    while((pos = pwd.find(delimiter)) != string::npos)
    {
        token = pwd.substr(0,pos);
        pwd.erase(0,pos + delimiter.length());
        for(int i = 0; i<aux->childs.size(); i++)
        {
            if(aux->childs[i]->name.compare(token))
            {
                aux=aux->childs[i];
            }
        }
    }
    if(aux->names.find(name) != string::npos)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
}

}
```

Comment: What happens after `aux=aux->childs[i];`, if `i` remains the same?

Comment: What do you mean?I don't understand the question, i is either 0, or goes from 0 to the size of the vector.

Answer (score 2):

I am kinda dumb, I figured it out, didn't have ==0 in the if with compare, sorry for bothering